# Servlet: blank screen

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am using Eclipse IDE and below code gives blank screen on the browser. I dont know why its showing blank screen. Is there any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class Ch1Servlet
 */
public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        Date dat=new Date();
        System.out.println(dat);
        out.println("<html>" + "<body>" + "<h1>Heello world</h1>" + dat + "</body>" + "</html>");       
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

Please find Deployment descriptor file.
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Monte</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Ch1Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Ch1Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Ch1Servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Ch1Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Ch1Servlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please show your `serlvet-mapping` `url` and how you try to access this servlet. You should also probably call `out.close()` once you are done with your `PrintWriter`.

Comment: Thank for your response!!.I have added my post with Deployment descripotor file.I have tried with the out.close still getting blank screen.

Comment: What is your request url?

Comment: Unless your class is in the default package (no package), you should put the full Class path (eg. `com.myapp.Ch1Servlet`)

Comment: You might want to try doing `out.flush()` before `out.close()` as well.

Comment: Could you add `response.setContentType("text/html");` before PrintWriter out in doGet method?

Comment: @Omer:I have added response.setContentType("text/html") still getting blank screen as output.

Comment: @Soturios:My class is in default package only.

Comment: @Arsen:Request URL is http://localhost:8080/Monte/Ch1Servlet

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  package package;


 /**
   *
   * @author 
   */
   public class Ch1Servlet  extends HttpServlet {



/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        //you code here
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new MyException(exc);
    }finally{
            out.close()
        }
}


// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">

/** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/** 
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/** 
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}
// </editor-fold>
}
```

The above code accept both get and post

Comment: I have written in the same way as you mentioned.but still getting blank screen:(

Comment: You have some System.out.println() statement. Was the date string printed out to the console? Any error log in the server? And when you right click your browser and choose "view source", do you see any html source?

Comment: @Surge:Thank for your response.No it is not showing Date on console.I have checked the source too.Source is also coming as blank only.